# "take too long" vs "take a long time"

Tags: grammar

As far as I know "take too long " and "take a long time " are different. And I once read two examples on Internet they considered to be incorrect.As follows :

1)Let's plan on using email to inform the client, because regular mail (takes a long time) .

2)Please expect  for the project  to be completed by 2013 because creating an index (takes too long).

Correct Ans: 1) takes too long 2) take a long time

My question is, why those are incorrect?  what's the difference? Would anybody give me detailed explanations?

Comment: "Take too long" means that the time spent is in excess of what we want. It is undesirable. "Take a long time" means _only_ that the time spent is long, but implies no judgment of the desirability of that length of time. Your answers are correct!

Answer (score 1):

***Take a long time*** is an idiom, a special meaning of *take* referring to duration of some event.

- *The train took a long time to pass.*

It's one version of the `Event` *take* `Duration` idiom

- *Making egg rolls takes all day ~ It takes all day to make egg rolls.*

*T**ake too long*** uses the same durational sense of *take*, but the [*too* marks it as a Negative](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf).
*Too `Adjective`* means 'so `Adjective` that `Not S`, where `Not S` is some negative outcome.

- *He was **too** sick to come. = He was so sick that he **didn't** come.*

Thus *take too long* means 'take so much time that something is wrong'.

- *The train took too long to pass.*

means that it was slow, or it was late, or the drivers honked their horns at it, or the speaker was irritated, or **something** -- details are not always specified. But something was out of expectation.

Answer (score 0):

> takes too long

can be used for a comparison of a single *thing* on its own or when comparing *things* (your first sentence)

> Walking home takes too long.
>   Let's drive home, walking home takes too long.

Whereas

> takes a long time

is used to describe the duration of a single *thing* (your second sentence)

> walking home *takes a long time*

Sometimes they can be used interchangeably

> Let's drive home, walking home takes too long.
>   Let's drive home, walking home takes a long time.

both sentences have the same meaning.

Comment: #Peter please consider this sentence - Please don't  take too long/ take a long time to get back to me. 

which one is correct?  And give me some more examples with explanations.

Comment: Both sentences are correct and understandable, the first is more usually used and has more of a "hurry back" feel to it. Common usage would be "don't take too long" to tell someone to be quick, "taking a long time" to describe that they are slow.